# Number of Fringes obtained on Interference of Lights of different Wavelengths

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, interference, double-slit-experiment, wavelength

The Question goes as follows:

[image]

I am stuck at the part where we obtain General Equation for Path Difference of two Interfering Lights. Since Wavelength of those Interfering Lights are different, so I cannot apply the equation $\Delta \psi = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Delta x$, and thus cannot find the General Condition for the Position of Dark Fringes.

 
Would be really grateful if someone suggests me how to tackle these kinds of Problems.

Comment: I think the question has no definite answer. Since each wavelength generates a (formally) infinite number of dark fringes, the only thing that reduces that number is either 1) screen size or 2) diffraction by non-zero width slits.

Comment: I think the idea is you need to count how many places are there where both banks produce a dark fine at the same place.

Comment: @ThePhoton Even then, there's an infinite number of those (they're evenly spaced).

Comment: @Miyase You do actually obtain some sort of Limiting Condition by ∆x = d sinθ, where **d** is the Distance btw the slits (since sinθ cannot be >1), and then you can relate ∆x=(2n+1)λ/2 for dark fringes, and thus you get Limiting Condition for **n** (Number of Dark Fringes). But since this equation can be used for Interference of Lights of same Wavelength only, I am having some difficulty using that, which is basically my doubt.

Comment: @ThePhoton Do you mean Superimposition Principle??..... Is it valid here too?

Comment: Since these are different wavelength beams, they are  incoherent (assuming no extreme measures were taken to produce coherent beams). Therefore for practical purposes the intensities of the beams add, rather than the electric fields (which is usually what we mean when we talk about the superposition principle in optics).

Comment: @ThePhoton Regarding $\Delta x=d \sin(\theta)$, are you sure? This looks a lot like diffraction by a slit, in which case d would be the width of a slot (which is assumed to be vanishingly small here). I've just redone the full computation (within the framework of Fraunhofer diffraction), so such factor appears and the size of the interference pattern is (formally) infinite.

Comment: @Miyase, Geometrically, $\theta$ must be between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. You can't use the small-angle approximation over the whole width of the screen. If you want the fringes to be equally spaced you need to make the screen be a half-pipe around the slits rather than a plane.

Comment: Unfortunately now that I actually try to solve the problem this way, I don't get any of the answers that you're allowed to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the screen is irrelevant.

The condition for a maximum is $n \lambda = d\sin \theta$ where $d$ Is the slit separation and $n$ is the order of the fringe.
Using this formula with $\theta = \pm \pi/2$ will give you the number of bright fringes either side of the central maximum and this eliminates two of the answers.

The wavelengths have been chosen so that they are in a simple ratio $(9/7)$ which makes finding the position of the minima relatively easy.

For coincidence of minima at a certain position you must have $(n+1/2)420 = (m+1/2)540 = d\sin \theta$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers which you need to find.